# Illegal argument for setLoggerLevel() loggingmxbean

Tags: jsp, jconsole, java.util.logging, mbeans

I am getting Illegal argument(Bad Level) exception when i try to call setLoggerLevel() through jconsole. The method is invoked successfully if i give the level as "INFO". anything other than that throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are passing in a valid logger name?  From the java doc in the "Throws" section:

IllegalArgumentException - if loggerName is not a registered logger or if levelName is not null and an invalid value.

This is the same doc from either Sun (Oracle) or IBM.

IBM seems to have a buggy implementation for this that I've seen on WebSphere 7.0 where it will throw a NullPointerException for the log level even though, according to the java doc, you are allowed to do this.

IF you have any control over the application and can create a new MBean, you could internally use the logging API directly and avoid the use of the LoggingMXBean altogether. Then you could control the logging level via jconsole and your new MBean.

Answer (score 0):

The valid levels supported by `setLoggerLevel` are as follows:

- OFF
- SEVERE
- WARNING
- INFO
- CONFIG
- FINE
- FINER
- FINEST
- ALL

For more details, see `java.util.logging.Level`.